# Accessing async variable of service

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services

This is part of my first Angular 4 project. I am currently able to call the searchCall function just fine from a search bar, but the data being stored in tweetsData doesn't seem to be in scope with my *ngFor call in app.component.html, as well as being an asynchronous backend call to the twitter api. I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined, so I must not have the observable setup correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

twitter.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class TwitterService {
  searchQuery: string = '';
  tweetsData;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('TwitterService created');
    this.getBearerToken();
  }

  getBearerToken() {
    // get bearer token from twitter api
    var headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/authorize', {headers: headers}).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  getTweetsData():Observable<any> {
    return this.tweetsData;
  }

  searchCall() {
    console.log('searchCall made');
    console.log(this.searchQuery);
    var headers = new Headers();
    var searchTerm = 'query=' + this.searchQuery;

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/search', searchTerm, {headers: headers}).subscribe((res) => {
      this.tweetsData = res.json().data.statuses;
    });
  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { TwitterService } from './twitter.service';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'custom-styles/app.component.css' ],
  providers: [TwitterService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  searchQuery: string = '';
  tweetsData;
  expandedNewTweetBox: boolean = false;

  public modalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private http: Http, private twitterService: TwitterService, private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.twitterService.getTweetsData().subscribe(
      data => this.tweetsData = data
    )
  }

  public openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
...
<div *ngIf="tweetsData">
  <div *ngFor="let item of tweetsData" class="col-12">
...
```

navbar.component.html

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Chiller" aria-label="Search Chiller" [(ngModel)]="twitterService.searchQuery" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" (click)="twitterService.searchCall()">Go!</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You never call `searchCall`

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I do. The call is in another part of app.component.html which I omitted because I tested the call to the search function and it works as expected.

Comment: You shouldn't assume caching like that. You probably have a race condition or something.

Comment: I apologize, the call to searchCall is made in another component 'navbar.component'. I have added the relevant code from that file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, you have `providers: [TwitterService]` at the component level, that means the component gets a separate service instance with its own state. That is normally fine, except your service is stateful and expects to be a singleton.

Comment: I removed the providers in my components and added it to my app.module file and that solved the problem of multiple instances, but not of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Comment: `tweetsData` won't have a value if `searchCall` hasn't completed its POST.

Comment: Have you tried declaring 'tweetsData: Observable<any[]>'?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, that is why i tried using an observable to notify subscribed components when a change was made to the `tweetsData` variable. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @JoeWu I don't believe that solves this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem, like pointed out in comments, having your providers array at component level will mean that you have separate instances of services, so it's not shared at all. So remove those!

Also you have race conditions, like also mentioned in comments.

I understand that you want to have subscribers listen to when `tweetsData` has values. What you need to do, is provide these subscribers with  **observables** What you are doing now:

```ts
getTweetsData():Observable<any> {
  return this.tweetsData;
}
```

returns an array (assumingly), not an **observable of an array**. You cannot subscribe to a "regular" array.

So what I would do, is to declare an Observable in the service:

```ts
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

// don't use 'any', type your data instead
// you can also use a 'Subject' if the subscribers are always listening
private tweetsData = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
public tweetsData$ = this.tweetsData.asObservable();
```

then when you get your data, call `next()`:

```ts
searchCall() {
  // ....
  this.http.post(...)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      this.tweetsData.next(res.json().data.statuses)
    });
}
```

Then you have your subscribers listen to this observable, like:

```ts
constructor(private twitterService: TwitterService) {
  twitterService.tweetsData$
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.tweetsData = data;
    });
}
```

That should do it. Further reading from the docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: That fixed the problem! You're the best, thank you so much. The one thing I had to change was `tweetsData$` had to be public so that I could reference it in `app.component.ts`

Comment: Oh sorry, you are completely correct, that it needs to be `public`! Glad to hear that the solution worked, have a nice weekend and happy coding! :)

Answer (score -1):

what is the type of tweetsData in twitter.service.ts

```
   getTweetsData():Observable<any> 
    {
    return this.tweetsData;
    }
```

Is this function returning a observable ?
If this is not an observable , you can return Observable.of(this.tweetsData)

```
 getTweetsData():Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of(this.tweetsData) ;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the property `of` does not exist for `Observable`. My intention for `getTweetsData` was to watch the variable `tweetsData` and notify subscribed components when a change was made to that variable. I could be wrong and I should know this, but I believe `tweetsData` will hold an array of JSON objects soon after a call to `searchCall` is made (not immediately, thus being async).

Comment: In latest version of RxJS we can import it like that:

import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; , and use Observable.of({})

Comment: tweetsData will hold an array of JSON objects but it will not be an Observable. To observe/watch  the change in tweetsData , you have to return a Oservable from function getTweetsData() . You can either use Obeservable .of  or create Behaviour Subject and make a observable with that object as mentioned in  AJT_82 's comment.