# Angular service and component

Tags: angular

In Angular im trying to access api data the is stored, and in another component trying to display that data but there seems to be lag.  Api is called in the service by app.module component and trying to access the data which is stored in a variable in another component. There seems to be small lag in between.

So when if first the load the app, data is not there but if i click another component and come back(the component where the data supposed to be displayed) the data is there.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class BusinessService {
  private usersUrl = 'api/newBusiness';
  newBusinessApiData;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getNewBusiness(): any {
    return this.http.get(this.usersUrl).subscribe(response => {
      this.newBusinessApiData = response;
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

**//in business Component:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.businessData = this.service.newBusinessApiData;
    console.log('New business component' + this.businessData);
  }
```

so when I console log it, businessData is udnefined

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when i try to access the data initially, the variable is empty but if i click another component and come back the data is there.

Comment: If you post some code we may be able to help better

Comment: That is not a question, that is a statement. Please include your code *and* a question that you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

what type of lag are happened? and
how to use that variable (@Input) ? or access via service directly.

if your display data component is child component then it will wait for API call and then store data in variable then pass to the another component.
but can you please share more details of your API called.
if your API call is in for loop,
then every change of that variable are called (`ngOnChange`) in child component so that may be one reason.

Comment: you can edit your question and share your code in concise manner so other can get rid to your problem

Comment: I found the answer on this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065112/accessing-async-variable-of-service